# Call function of class using a variable function call

Tags: python

I'm trying to call a function from a Class thats name will change depending on what type of enemy is being instantiated. How can I accomplish this?

My attempt was this: `AssignClass.[self.Class](self)`

but obviously that sintax makes no sense

```
class Creature:

    def __init__(self, Name, Class):

        self.Name   = Name
        self.Class  = Class

        # Using a variable function call to remove
        # the need for a ton of 'if' statements

        AssignClass.[self.Class](self)

        # Basically automate doing this:

        if self.Class = "Orc":
            AssignClass.Orc(self)
        elif self.Class = "Wizard"
            AssignClass.Wizard(self)


class AssignClass:

    def Orc(Creature):
        Creature.Class='Orc'
        Creature.Health=100
        Creature.Mana=0

    def Wizard(Creature):
        Creature.Class='Wizard'
        Creature.Health=75
        Creature.Mana=200

Evil_Wizard = Creature("Evil Wizard", "Wizard")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve class methods using [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) and then just pass your `Creature` instance, e.g.:

```
class Creature:

    def __init__(self, Name, Class):
        self.Name   = Name
        self.Class  = Class
        getattr(AssignClass, Class)(self)
```

Btw. this is everything but a recommended style for Python classes, the least of which is that you're shadowing the `Creature` class in your `AssignClass` (which shouldn't be a class in the first place). I'd recommend you to read the [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) thoroughly.

Comment: I've been putting off actually learning PEP 8 for long enough I guess. I just program for fun so nothing I do matters anyways haha. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Played around a little more and found that I can use eval for this. (Safe as no user input can be added here)

```
class Creature:

    def __init__(self, Name, Class):

        self.Name   = Name
        self.Class  = Class

        eval('AssignClass.'+Class)(self)
```